# Rerun application when a file is modified

Tags: shell

I currently want to restart an application when a file has not been modified in the last 2 minutes. For that I wrote a little script to do that (I am a beginner in shell code) but I get some errors and don't succeed to obtain the behaviour I would like :

```
while :
do
    find ./ -type f -mmin -2
    if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then
        echo OK     
    else
        JAR_FILE=jmxtrans-270-all.jar /appl/TCE/jmxtrans/jmxtrans.sh restart    
    fi
sleep 5m
done
```

Can you indicate me if it's the right way to do that ? 
Thanks!

Comment: Allright, now it's good but I get "OK" when I run the script, even if no files have been modified in the directory of the script, in the last two minutes. If the find command returns nothing, it should execute the else condition ?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    if [ $[ $(date +%s) - $(stat -c %X <your_file>)] -gt $[2*60] ]; then
        # reset application here
    else
        echo "ok"
    fi  
    sleep 1
done
```

- `date +%s` return current timestamp
- `stat -c %X <your_file>` return last modified time in timestamp

Answer (score 1):

find returns always a zero return code. May use something like this:

```
while :
do
    count=$(find ./ -type f -mmin -2)
    if [ "$count" != "0" ]; then
        echo OK     
    else
        JAR_FILE=jmxtrans-270-all.jar /appl/TCE/jmxtrans/jmxtrans.sh restart    
    fi
sleep 5m
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely convinced on using the `find` command with `./`, if my understanding is correct and all you need to do is monitor some random `file` ( say `/var/log/file.log` ) based on last access time, you could try `stat`

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$1"
THRESHOLD=120
while [ 1 ] ;
do
    #Get the last accesstime as unixtime stamp
    last_access_time=$(stat -c %X $file)

    #Current time as unixTimeStamp
    current_time=$(date +%s)

    #difference
    diff=`echo "$currnet_time - $last_access_time" | bc`

    # Threshold here is 120 seconds
    if [ $diff < $THRESHOLD ]; 
    then
       echo "Do something "
    fi

    sleep $THRESHOLD;
done
```